# Receive a request through AWS API Gateway using websockets and invoke a php script using AWS Lambda

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Kinda lost on which services do I need to use, the idea is to build a server-less application using AWS services, here's a more detailed explanation on I'm looking for:

1. Client sends a request using websockets.
2. AWS API Gateway receives the request and invokes a lambda function.
3. The lambda function runs a php worker using Bref (https://bref.sh/).
4. The php worker requires another php file which connects to a 3rd party using HTTP to request data (we have several of these so we're going to wake several workers probably for 1 single request from the client).
5. The data obtained is returned all the way back to the client.

So what I want to accomplish is to avoid using HTTP until point 5, now I'm totally lost in regards to this being doable or not, where do I host my php files? do I need to use AWS SQS to invoke the lambda function?

Any help would be appreciated guys, trying to ready through the official Amazon documentation is quite complex.

Comment: You mentioned Bref, you host your files in the directory where you ran `composer require bref/bref` followed by `bref init` which creates a `serverless.yml` for you.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda Function is essentially a container that runs on a certain runtime.

Since PHP is not supported as an out-of-the-box runtime, you'll have to use a custom runtime.

Here's a great example by AWS for creating a Layer for PHP - https://github.com/aws-samples/php-examples-for-aws-lambda/tree/master/0.1-SimplePhpFunction

Another example, this one is for creating a custom runtime for PHP by using Docker - https://github.com/aws-samples/php-examples-for-aws-lambda/tree/master/0.7-PHP-Lambda-functions-with-Docker-container-images